# How can we understand that "diagonal part" of a surface integral is zero via a continuum limit of finite sum?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let us consider the usual derivation of the gaussian integral:
\begin{align}
\left(\int dx e^{-ax^2}\right)\left(\int dy e^{-ay^2}\right) =\int\int dx dy e^{-a(x^2 + y^2)} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.
\end{align}
If we extract the **"diagonal part"** of the double integral, which is $y = x$,
\begin{align}
\int dx \int_{y=x} dy e^{-2ax^2}
\end{align}
is zero, because the integral measure is zero.

However, how can I understand this result via the continuum limit of finite sum?

I mean, I consider
\begin{align}
\int dx f(x) = \lim_{L \rightarrow \infty}\left(\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L}{N}\sum_{k = -\frac{N}{2}}^{k = +\frac{N}{2}} f\left(\frac{L}{N}k\right) \right).
\end{align}
Once I forget detail treatments of limits, then
\begin{align}
\int dx f(x) \int dy f(y) \supset  \lim_{L \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{L' \rightarrow \infty}  \left(\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L}{N}\sum_{k = -\frac{N}{2}}^{k = +\frac{N}{2}} f\left(\frac{L}{N}k\right) \right)\left(\lim_{N' \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L'}{N'}\sum_{l = -\frac{N'}{2}}^{l = +\frac{N'}{2}} f\left(\frac{L'}{N'}l\right) \right),
\end{align}
which **I do not understand how the diagonal part $k = l$ is suppressed to be zero.**

In physics, sometimes the right hand side comes first, and we should take its continuum limit. Often, such the diagonal part is ignored. However, I think there is some mathematical reasons to get it.
If we start from the left hand side, then the integral will be a surface integral by definition. However, what I need to understand when the right hand side comes first?